# Session variable is lost in IE on redirect

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, model-view-controller, session-cookies

I have an MVC application and I am using a session variable to store a variable to identify the logged in user. This is working fine everywhere except IE. The first login will work, but if I logout, which removes the session variable, and then log back in, it will not set the session variable again. I am doing a Response.Redirect back to the login page after logout.

I have tried multiple things including changing to a Server.Transfer request and setting a bogus P3P header because apparently IE still reads this! The domain does not have an underscore which apparently is also an issue in IE. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

```
Login:
Session.Add("UserID", extr_user.extr_id);

Logout:
Session.Remove("UserID");
Response.Redirect(Url.Action("Login", "Home"));
```

EDIT

Test code to simulate issue with lost session variable, the issue is apparent running both on server and localhost

Download the code [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JLSf9sJeM-nS78P7K-P75aJdbBgZnHG2/view)

Home Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Home()
    {
        if (Session["UserID"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect(Url.Action("Login"));
        }
        return View();
    }

    public string doLogin(string Email, string Password)
    {
        Session.Add("UserID", 1);
        return Url.Action("Home");
    }

    public void Logout()
    {
        Session.Remove("UserID");
        Response.Redirect(Url.Action("Login"));
    }
}
```

Home.cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Logout", "Home")">Logout</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Login.cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title></title>
        @model LoginTest.Models.User
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function Login() {
                var email = $("#Username").val();
                var password = $("#Password").val();            
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("doLogin", "Home")',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: { Email: email, Password: password },
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (data) {
                        window.location.replace(data);
                    },
                    Error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Username)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username)
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password)
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" id="btnLogin" onclick="Login()" value="Login" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you got any caching going on that needs to be cleared

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the responses, apologies it's the first time I've posted. I have created a test application to simulate the issue which is only apparent in IE both running from server and local host. I have edited my post to include this

Comment: I'd suggest changing `doLogin` to be a POST endpoint, and to return `ActionResult` rather than `string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem here, IE was caching the ajax call. 2 steps for resolution, firstly add cache: false to the ajax arguments. Secondly, any console.logs you have in the jquery function, remove them as ie will still then cache the results.

Comment: I suggest that you coud mark your answer as solution if it solved your problem, and this will be helpful for someone meets with the same problem.